# Navigation reverse push action

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How can I know, inside a ViewController, when the reverse push happened? (Like the prepareForSegue method) Cause this one (prepareForSegue) does not respond to this action (reverse push)

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? And I am not sure this question actually makes sense. Please add more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement [viewWillDisappear:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillDisappear%3a). If [self.isMovingFromParentViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/isMovingFromParentViewController) is YES, then your View Controller is being popped.

```
- (void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    if ( self.isMovingFromParentViewController ) {
        // ...
        NSLog(@"%@",  self.navigationController.topViewController ) ;
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: And is it possible to know the object of the next class or is it the same that came from the push action?

Comment: Sure. `self.navigationController.topViewController` is the View Controller that is appearing after the pop, and the `class` method will give you its class.

Comment: In my case it's a TableView and it says that is incompatible, is there a solution?

Comment: What exactly does the error log say? If you have the user pressing a "Back" button to pop a View Controller (which takes them back to the previous View Controller), than there must be a UINavigationController present. Does your storyboard look [something like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/EMuN6.png)

Comment: Exactly like that example. Is there a way to over come the lack of a ViewController?

Comment: If you add `NSLog(@"self.navigationController.topViewController is: %@",  self.navigationController.topViewController ) ;` to the method `viewWillDisappear`, what do you see in the logs? Does it give you a specific error, or does it successfully log what the topViewController is?

Comment: It logs this: <FirstTableController: 0x752f020> (FirstTableController is my tableviewcontroller) it doesn't give me a specific error.